# Can we embed executable jar file in c++ resource and run it from memory?

Tags: java, c++

I hava a very simple java executable jar file, beside, i also have a simple c++ program. I want to embed executable jar file in to the c++ resource and load it to the memory and eventually run it through my c++ program. I completely know how to embed other files, also i can embed portable exe file and run it from the memory without writing the file to the disk.

this my test.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void RunFromMemory(char*, char*);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrib;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     HGLOBAL hResData;
     HRSRC   hResInfo;
     void    *pvRes;
     DWORD dwSize;
     char* lpMemory;
     HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
     char buf[_MAX_PATH]; 
     GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, _MAX_PATH);
     LPCTSTR szResName =(LPCTSTR) MAKEINTRESOURCE(101);

    hResInfo = FindResource(hModule, szResName,"EXEN");
    hResData = LoadResource(hModule, hResInfo);
    pvRes =  LockResource(hResData)
    if ((hResInfo != NULL) &&(hResData != NULL) &&(pvRes != NULL))
    { 
        dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResInfo);
        lpMemory = (char*)malloc (dwSize);
        memset(lpMemory,0,dwSize);
        memcpy (lpMemory, pvRes, dwSize);
        RunFromMemory(lpMemory,argv[0]);  
    }

    return 0;
}

void RunFromMemory(char* pImage,char* pPath)
{
   DWORD dwWritten = 0;
   DWORD dwHeader = 0;
   DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
   DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
   DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
   DWORD firstSection = 0;
   DWORD previousProtection = 0;
   DWORD jmpSize = 0;

   IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
   IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

   PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
   STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
   CONTEXT pContext;

   char* pMemory;
   char* pFile;
   memcpy(&IDH,pImage,sizeof(IDH));
   memcpy(&INH,(void*)((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew),sizeof(INH));

   dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
   pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
   memset(pMemory,0,dwImageSize);
   pFile = pMemory;

   dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
   firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
   memcpy(Sections,(char*)(firstSection),
          sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)*INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

   memcpy(pFile,pImage,dwHeader);

   if((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
   {
       jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
   }
   else
   {
      jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
      jmpSize += 1;
      jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
   }

   pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

  for(dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
  {
      jmpSize = 0;
      dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
      memcpy(pFile,(char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData),dwSectionSize);

    if((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
    }
    else
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        jmpSize += 1;
        jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    }
    pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
}


   memset(&peStartUpInformation,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   memset(&peProcessInformation,0,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
   memset(&pContext,0,sizeof(CONTEXT));

   peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);

   if(CreateProcess(NULL,pPath,&secAttrib,NULL,false,CREATE_SUSPENDED, 
        NULL,NULL,&peStartUpInformation,&peProcessInformation))
   {
       pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
       GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
       VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&previousProtection);
       WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),pMemory,dwImageSize,&dwWritten);
       WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)pContext.Ebx + 8),&INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase,4,&dwWritten);
       pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
       SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
       VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,previousProtection,0);
       ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
   }
   free(pMemory);
}
```

and resource.rc file:

```
101    EXEN      "sample.exe"
```

i use windres to create resource.res file as follow:

```
windres resource.rc -O coff -o resource.res
```

and eventually compile my c++ as follow:

```
g++ test.cpp resource.res -o test.exe
```

now i want to embed an executable jar file as resource, load it in to memory and run it through my test.cpp

Comment: Jar files do not contain executable code the way you think. They contain Java bytecode and require the entire java runtime to be executed. I don't think there's a trivial way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm actually familiar with Java, but all I want to do is call java and pass the embedded jar file to it to run. But I must also point out that I do not want to save the jar file to the disk.

Comment: Why not save -> execute -> delete?

Comment: Because of performance issues, as the file size may be large and it can be expensive to write each time. In this example I used a simple file, but it is not always valid.

Comment: So you want to, in effect, exec "java --jar foo.jar" but foo.jar doesn't exist?

Comment: No, i want to embed a jar file in c++ resource, after that, i want to load it into the memory, not from hard disk by address, i want to load the one embedded into the resource and run the that jar file by using jni from memory.